# Historical abbreviation of 'multiplied'

Tags: notation, math-history

I was reading Bayes' essay "An Essay towards Solving a Problem in the Doctrine of Chances" and noticed the following bit of notation

[image: confusing bit of Bayes' Essay]

The meaning of the n+1 term is clear from the rest of the essay (in modern terms it would be surrounded by parentheses rather than have the bar), but the ×<sup>*d*</sup> part confused me. Initially I thought it meant "multiply d times", but there is no numeric variable *d* elsewhere, leading me to think that ×<sup>*d*</sup> is meant to be an abbreviation for "multiplied".

Has ×<sup>*d*</sup> been used in other works to mean multiplied? Here, it seems to mean that in context (it fits the sentence, at least), but other historical examples would increase my confidence.

A copy of the paper is [here](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rstl.1763.0053). The image is from the bottom of page 29 of the PDF.

Comment: In context, could it by a typo? That is, does it make sense to just be x d with the d not raised?

Comment: Given the effort involved in letterpress printing, that sort of typo is unlikely. Also, using superscript final letters for abbreviations used to be quite a common thing.

Comment: I don't think it would make sense, since that would mean multiplied by d, but there aren't any variables d in the paper (except for about 13 pages back, but that refers to a point, not a number).

Comment: The first **x** does not have any raised *d*. On the same page, clearly **x** is not the same as the algebraic **_x_** also used, and has superscripts which seem to represent powers.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It being that convention would make sense, and it seems to be used elsewhere in the paper with the 'multiplied by' meaning.

Comment: The formula also appears right at the top of page 43 (headed "[412]") where ×d is not included at all.

Comment: @AndrewLeach So it does. I missed that. It seems pretty clear that this is at worst an ad hoc abbreviation of multiplied. I suppose it would still be interesting to know if it was used in other books or papers.

Comment: I would guess that the "x" is being used to mean "times" (still a common convention), and "x-superscript-2" would be used to mean "squared".  I suspect that the meaning of "d" is somehow implied in the text.  But this question probably really belongs on one of the math forums.

Comment: But I will note that the bar over "n + 1" is suggestive of notation I've seen where the bar means "average" or some such.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It also appears as the very next formula on the next page (headed "[339]") at the end of the first paragraph of "Rule 1" albeit split over 2 lines.

Comment: Note that "d" is defined on page 19.

Comment: @HotLicks A bar over a variable can mean the average in modern notation (although  over x+1 is undefined) but in Bayes' day it was the equivalent of  parenthesis in modern notation. However parenthesis had been used for grouping as far back as 1557, see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_mathematical_notation]

Answer (score 1):

There is a transcription of the paper originally from UCLA but now on the [WayBackMachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20110410085940/http://www.stat.ucla.edu/history/essay.pdf) It uses two different "x". The UCLA copy still uses the archaic bar in place of parenthesis.

In modern notation I copy it as:

```
(n+1) x EX^d
```

Where the lower case *x* is multiplication, the upper case *X* is a variable and *^d* is exponentiation.

Upper case *X* is a variable used many times in that area of the paper.

I think the real answer to this question is "Go and find a different (newer) transcription of the paper and draw your own conclusions."